# How can I call ajax only on the textarea that was expanded using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I have no problem expanding the textarea or calling ajax when the textarea expands. However when I have three textareas, whenever I expand the textarea, all three will call the ajax. I want to call whichever textarea was expanded. I had no idea to do so. I have tried $(this).closest('textarea').attr('id'), it doesn't work. help, appreciate.

```js
$.fn.TextAreaExpander = function(minHeight, maxHeight) {

   var hCheck = !($.browser.msie || $.browser.opera);
      var prevHeight;

   // resize a textarea
   function ResizeTextarea(e) {

    // event or initialize element?
    e = e.target || e;

    // find content length and box width
    var vlen = e.value.length, ewidth = e.offsetWidth;
    if (vlen != e.valLength || ewidth != e.boxWidth) {

     if (hCheck && (vlen < e.valLength || ewidth != e.boxWidth)) e.style.height = "0";
     var h = Math.max(e.expandMin, Math.min(e.scrollHeight, e.expandMax));

     e.style.overflow = (e.scrollHeight > h ? "auto" : "hidden");
     e.style.height = h + "px";
     
     if(e.style.height > prevHeight)  // throw the alert only if the height is not same as the previous one
      load_expand_text();// the function that will be called when expand
     e.valLength = vlen;
     e.boxWidth = ewidth;
           prevHeight = e.style.height;  // save the height
     
    }

    return true;
   };

   // initialize
   this.each(function() {

    // is a textarea?
    if (this.nodeName.toLowerCase() != "textarea") return;

    // set height restrictions
    var p = this.className.match(/expand(\d+)\-*(\d+)*/i);
    this.expandMin = minHeight || (p ? parseInt('0'+p[1], 10) : 0);
    this.expandMax = maxHeight || (p ? parseInt('0'+p[2], 10) : 99999);

    // initial resize
    ResizeTextarea(this);

    // zero vertical padding and add events
    if (!this.Initialized) {
     this.Initialized = true;
     $(this).css("padding-top", 0).css("padding-bottom", 0);
     $(this).bind("keyup", ResizeTextarea).bind("focus", ResizeTextarea);
    }
    
   });

   return this;
  };



function load_expand_text(){
 var data={ 
            action: 'load_expand_text',
   current_load:'499',
      userVoteNonce : UserAjaxVote.userVoteNonce,

};
  $.ajax({
   url: UserAjaxVote.ajaxurl,
   type:'POST',
   cache: false,
   data:data,
            beforeSend: function() {

  },
   success: function(data){
    $('.expand9-999').html(data);

   }
    });//ajax
    
   };//function load_expand_text
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<textarea class="expand9-999" id="exer_t"></textarea>
<textarea class="expand9-999" id="diet_t"></textarea>
<textarea class="expand9-999" id="run_t"></textarea>
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that your 3 textarea objects has the same class, and when you use the class selector, you put the result of you ajax call in all textareas, with this line:

```
$('.expand9-999').html(data);
```

You can pass the id of the textarea to the **load_expand_text** function and then set the html just for the right textarea object.

You could also try use the resible plugin of jQuery UI, and put your code inside the function, like this:

```
$("textarea").resizable({
resize: function() {
    // your code and ajax call here, or something like this:
   load_expand_text($(this))
}});
```

And the load_expand_text function:

```
function load_expand_text(objtextarea){
... ajax call
success: function(data){
        $(objtextarea).html(data);

        }
```

Hope it helps.